# TypeError - count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm starting in laravel, I'm trying to make a dashboard but when I added this code to dashboard.blade.php (I deleted the previous code because it used Jetstream)
The line that is giving an error:

```
 @if (count($events) > 0)
```

Code body:

```
 @extends('layouts.main')


 @section('title', 'Dashboard')


 @section('content')



 <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 dashboard-title-container">

     <h1>My Events</h1>

 </div>

 <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 dashboard-events-container"> /* This is where you will have the list of events*/
     @if (count($events) > 0)
     @else
     <p>You have no events yet, <a href="/events/create">create event</a></p>
     @endif
 </div>

 @endsection
```

My php is 8.0.7

Comment: Show your controller codes in which you're loading the data

Comment: It seems you are trying to use count() on a null variable. you need to show your controller for better understanding of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the `events` relationship on your User model.

If you define a one-to-many relationship you will always get a Collection when accessing the property (dynamic property) of the model.

```
// User model

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

With that you can access the relationship as a property and pass the Collection to your view:

```
return view('events.dashboard', ['events' => auth()->user()->events]);
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent Relationships - One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) - `hasMany`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem.

Comment: @TatianaScheideggerdeAguiar no problem, please accept the answer if it solved your problem and upvote if you found it helpful, thanks